# Generalized projectile motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, projectile

> Toss an object from the surface of earth at speed $V_1=\sqrt{MG/R}$. Here $R$ is the radius of the earth and $M$ is the mass of the earth and $G$ is universal gravitational constant. How long will it take for it to fall back?

My approach is to calculate the maximum height of the toss. Let the maximum height be $h$ above the ground and $m$ be the mass of the object. Using the relationship between kinetic energy and gravitational energy we get $$\Delta E_k=-\Delta E_p\Rightarrow\frac{GMm}R-\frac{GMm}{R+h}=\frac12m\sqrt{MG/R}^2$$ . Thus $h=R$ but how to get the time? I suppose the $\text{Theorem of Momentum}$ is the most suitable only the gravitational force changes with the object's position.

Comment: Kepler's Laws! The trajectory of the object is a degenerate ellipse.

Comment: @DanDan0101 maybe you can explain how the potential is of the $1/r$ form?

Comment: @DanDan0101 Could you provide an answer with this idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending your method slightly, using energy conservation
$$
\frac 1 2 m\dot{y}^2 - \frac 1 2 mv_0^2 = \frac{GMm}{R+y} - \frac{GMm}{R}
$$
Here, $y$ is the height from the earth's surface, $v_0$ is the initial speed, and $\dot{y} \equiv \frac{dy}{dt}$ is the speed of the particle. Substituting,
$$
\dot{y}^2 = \frac{2GM}{R + y} - \frac{GM}{R} \implies \dot{y} = \pm \sqrt{\frac{2GM}{R + y} - \frac{GM}{R}}
$$
We want
$$
T = 2\int_0^R \frac{1}{|\dot{y}|} dy
$$
Complicated integrals aren't my speciality – I stuck it into WolframAlpha and it gave me
$$
T = (\pi+2)\sqrt{\frac{R^3}{GM}}
$$

Comment: Could you tell me what're $y$ and $\dot y$?

Comment: How can the time be calculated by applying calculus to speed?

Comment: @youthdoo Sorry, just realised I made a mistake. My apologies. Let me change my answer again...

Comment: @youthdoo Perhaps you were confused because of my error, but I'll explain anyway. The time taken to travel an infinitesimal distance is that distance divided by the speed. So the total time taken is the integral of that.

Comment: Why does y go from 0 to R? Shouldn't we evaluate y from 0 to $Y_{max}$

Comment: @jensenpaull Look at my question, where $y_\text{max}=R$ is proved.

Comment: Never mind, I didnt calculate y_max, which is R, your correct.

Comment: Your integral does not give a time in seconds.

Comment: @R.W.Bird Well spotted, I think the $\sqrt{GM}$ was in the wrong place. I'll edit it